# Task availability to certain groups of performers

Tags: toloka

In my project I need to give access to certain groups of performers. How do I make a task available to mobile device users? and How do I select performers of a certain age?

Answer (score 0):

To select an audience for your task, set requirements for performers using filters (region, language, gender, age, and so on) and skills. Don't disregard filters by language and region. Otherwise, your tasks will be available to any user from any country. Many of them might not know the language of your task, which means they won't be able to read instructions and perform tasks efficiently. So the overall result may disappoint you. To avoid this, set pool filters by language and region.

Check about how to select performers for your tasks in the Requester's guide.
https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/filters.html

1. Set the "Client = Mobile Toloka" filter.
2. Use filters by date of birth and specify a range.